# Angular window.localStorage different subdomain

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, local-storage

I'm using Angularjs in my project. I've set `window.localStorage['foo']`, but I need to use the data in other subdomains. For example, it starts on `domain.com` and goes to `sub1.domain.com` => `sub2.domain.com`.

So, when I try to use with the subdomains, I cannot access `window.localStorage['foo']`, and I need to set everything again.

Is there another way to do it?

Thanks

[ SOLUTION ]

I used ng-cookies and works good.
angular/bower-angular-cookies

```
$cookies.put('myCookie', value, { domain: 'domain.com'} );
```

Thanks all answers!

Comment: This isn't an angular issue, this is an HTML5 issue.  Local Storage in browsers is isolated by HTML5 Origin (scheme + hostname + unique port).  In other words, `http://domain.com`, `https://domain.com`, `http://domain.com:5000`, `http://sub1.domain.com`, `https://sub1.domain.com`, etc. each have their own isolated storage.

Comment: @Steve while that is most definitely a duplicate discussion, I'm not sure that the answer is viable for the poster, as using an iframe in angular isn't really viable.  I still don't think this is an angular issue specifically, or that there is a workable solution, but the duplicate feels a bit too generic.

Comment: Can you not just go old school and use a cookie?  Otherwise consider a service call.

Comment: it's not possible to post an answer (even a self answer) when a question is marked as a duplicate.